# Changing the text in a UILabel based on Date

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsdate

How would I make a UILabel say "Its January!" in the month of January and "Its February!" in the month of February etc.?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: use [NSDate date], it gives current(todays) date

Comment: @santhu what do you mean?

Comment: Proper English would be "It's January" (or "It is January").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current date by doing `[[NSDate alloc] init]`, then format it to what you want(in this case the month name) by using NSDateFormatter and the format `@"MMMM"`].

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
NSString *monthName = [formatter stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];
NSString *whatYouWant = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"It's %@", monthName];
NSLog(@"What you want = %@",whatYouWant);
```

Answer (score 2):

This function will help you with the months. The result you want you concatenate with the "Its" ... =)

```
- (NSString *) MonthNameString:(int) monthNumber
{
    NSDateFormatter * formate = [NSDateFormatter new];
    NSArray * monthNames = [formate standaloneMonthSymbols];
    NSString * monthName = [monthNames objectAtIndex:(monthNumber - 1)];

    return monthName;
}
```

Comment: "standaloneMonthSymbols", huh? I didn't know that one. I would have used an "MMMM" date formatter, as ansible suggests above. The richness of the Cocoa/Cocoa touch APIs never ceases to amaze me. Thanks for teaching me a new trick. (+1)